# C# foreach if loop panel color change

Tags: c#, winforms

Im trying to change colors of panels via foreach and if loop, but after the first if loop, all colors are the same and the code is not working.

```
IEnumerable<Panel> pnls = panel1.Controls.OfType<Panel>();
                    foreach (Panel pan in pnls)
                    {
                        foreach (var lbls in pnls)
                        {                                                   
                            if (lbls.BackColor == Color.FromArgb(224, 224, 224))
                            {
                                lbls.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 64, 0);                                                           
                            }
                           
                            if (lbls.BackColor == Color.FromArgb(0, 64, 0))
                            {
                                lbls.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(224, 224, 224);
                               
                            }                                     
                        }                           
                    }
```

Actually, what I want to do is this: when the button is pressed, if the panel is green, it will be red, if it is red, it will be green. I seem to understand that it is impossible to do this with this loop, how should I proceed? There is two foreach for, child panels.

Comment: Your nested foreach loops don't make sense. You're iterating over pnls in both.

Comment: Yeah `pan` is never used for anything so the outside loop serves no purpose except to repeat the inner loop multiple times. If the inner loop worked as intended, the outer loop would ultimately switch the colours with an uneven number of items in the collection or toggle them back to their starting state with an even number of items.

Comment: In addition to the above, the end result will always be (224, 224, 224) because even if you start with (224, 224, 224), the first `if` block turns the color into (0, 64, 0), and then the second `if` block turns it back into (224, 224, 224). You need to use an `else` or `else if` branch as mentioned in the answer below. As a side note, (224, 224, 224) is _not_ red by any stretch of the imagination. Perhaps you meant to use (224, 0, 0)?

Comment: If I dont nest, i cant reach the child panels. Secondly, thanks for if else loop idea.

Answer (score 1):

mybe `else` solve the problem:

```
    if (lbls.BackColor == Color.FromArgb(224, 224, 224))
    {
        lbls.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 64, 0);                                                           
    }
    else if (lbls.BackColor == Color.FromArgb(0, 64, 0))
    {
        lbls.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(224, 224, 224);
                           
    }
```

Comment: not working....

Answer (score 1):

```
if (lbls.BackColor == Color.FromArgb(224, 224, 224))
{
    lbls.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 64, 0);                                                           
}

if (lbls.BackColor == Color.FromArgb(0, 64, 0))
{
    lbls.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(224, 224, 224);
}
```

if the first condition is true, then the second one will be also true. To separate them, you need to use `else if` like this :

```
if (lbls.BackColor == Color.FromArgb(224, 224, 224))
{
    lbls.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 64, 0);                                                           
}
else if (lbls.BackColor == Color.FromArgb(0, 64, 0))
{
    lbls.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(224, 224, 224);
}
```

this will ensure that `BackColor` will be set once.

The other thing that you have is the looping. Both are looping over panels, so if you have for instance 5 panels, then your looping would iterates about 25 times. What I think you're looking for is that you need to loop over all panels, and then on each panel loop over all `Label`s. which makes sense.

here is a revised version :

```
foreach (Panel panel in panel1.Controls.OfType<Panel>())
{
        if (panel.BackColor == Color.FromArgb(224, 224, 224))
        {
            panel.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 64, 0);                                                           
        } 
        else  if (panel.BackColor == Color.FromArgb(0, 64, 0))
        {
            panel.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(224, 224, 224);        
        }
}
```

Comment: Still not working, my panels look like that: [link]https://www.hizliresim.com/hrmwigh . There is one main panel names as (panel1) and im trying to change color of the child panels (5x8)

Comment: @JozefStone link is broken, I have updated the code according to your comment

Comment: links work for me

Comment: @JozefStone I've checked the link again, and it's working now. It seems you need a technique that would give you a better maintainability to this grid-like panel. How about storing a reference to each panel in an array, so you can get the panel reference from the array by an array index ? (you could store the control name in the array for instance).

Comment: @JozefStone this would give a better control on the panels, so you will avoid looping over the panels each time you need to update one !